# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method'

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-error

Переделывал свою программу, и решил завернуть её в класс, компилятор вроде не жаловался, ошибок нету, но стоит мне её запустить как у меня вылазит ошибка

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Вот в этом кусочке кода:

```
arefm = sum((float(abs[i]) for i in range(0, int(len(abs))))) / int(len(abs))
```

Смотрел другие источники по такой же ошибке, но там было что-то вроде "Замените круглые скобки на квадратные или наоборот" Но у меня до этого всё работало, но вдруг перестало как я сделал программу в классе, с чем это может быть связано ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abs` - встроенное имя функции питона, поэтому выходит такая ошибка. Не используйте для своих переменных таких имён. Видимо, вы поменяли имя своего списка или что у вас там, но не везде, тут забыли поменять. Ну или у вас, например, этот список переменная экземпляра класса теперь, а вы её без `self.` оставили в этом коде. Но в любом случае - не используйте зарезервированные слова питона в качестве названий своих переменных или функций, а то потом сюрприз будет рано или поздно.